# Static IP or DHCP for TFS 2010

Tags: team-foundation-server

For TFS 2010 application tier. data tier and build server, What should be the best practice for IP address. Shall we give static IP available or we should use DHCP forthis.

Answer (score 4):

Use DHCP and a proper named.

That will make the network you place TFS on flexible, dynamic and future-friendly

Comment: Do you mean "configure DHCP to allocate a static address"? Thus allowing central management of IPs (and backup) while avoiding IP changes.

Comment: Giving both of you an upvote because you're both correct - it really comes down to what your organisation is already doing.

Comment: I second Farseeker. We used to do all static on the server; but we now only use static on infrastructure servers, and DHCP on everything else. But it really depends on what you're used to.

Comment: Thanks all. In our infrastructure we also use static for all infrastructure server and DHCP for others. Since we have done a test installation of TFS 2010 on three virtual server (one each for data, app and build tier) which uses DHCP for IP. 

We are having issues in TFS 2010 sharepoint Dashboard ..we tried to fix it by using second method give here http://davidrbrown.com/tag/rsinvalidreportparameter/ . This gives a error which says SQL is not able to communicate...That's why i thought is it because of IP by DHCP.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use static ip addresses on all "fixed" hosts\nodes such as servers, printers, etc.

Comment: Giving both of you an upvote because you're both correct - it really comes down to what your organisation is already doing.